# Norm stable via isomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

I wonder what makes a norm preserved via isomorphism? We used that property to prove that all norms are equivalent in finite-dimensional vector space.

Comment: I think, to prove that any norm on  a finite dimensional space are equivalent we do not need the concept of Isomorphism.Can you explain the proof of yours for the same ..

Comment: By fixing a base for any n-dimensional vector space E, we can build an isomorphism between it and IK^n. It is easy to show that all norms are equivalent in IK^n using the transitivity of the equivalence relation.